# Right to implement synchronized blocks for Netty server?

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, netty

I have been building a game server using Netty which may have thousands concurrent connections. I have known that in the server side those connections may share some but not only one worker threads thus it is not safe to let them to access freely shared data, e.g. to find, remove or add some objects to some common lists and maps. I am considering to add synchronized blocks to all code which access shared data. (For heavy tasks such as querying database I plan to use ExecutorService / Threads so synchronisation won’t be a big problem for those tasks).

I am still confused if it a good / common solution or there are better ways (than using synchronized blocks) to do that for Netty server.

Can someone give me some advices please. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Synchronized blocks (or their equivalent ReentrantLocks) are the only reliable way to access shared data. In asynchronous environment like Netty, however, the code inside synchronized block may not call to wait(), since this excludes current thread from serving. Usually synchronized block is an intermediate object in producer-consumer communication, and consumer calls to wait() when there is no data from producer. To avoid blocking, consumer, when data are not ready, places himself (or another object of type Runnable) into the intermediate object, and producer, when sending data, submits that Runnable to a thread pool (instead of calling to notify()).

Synchronized blocks are low-level facilities and should not be mixed with business logic. Instead, a communicating framework should be developed with adequate interface. An example of such framework is my [df4j](https://github.com/rfqu/df4j/blob/master/df4j-core/README.md) library.